# JSONException on trying to get a value from Json to String

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to get 2 values from Wikipedia with the next API link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500&utf8

because its generated by random, sometimes it doesn't return one of the values I need, but I will solve this later, currently I'm having a problem with accessing the two values I need in the Json, "title" and "source"

The returned Json is like this:

```
 {"batchcomplete":"","continue":{"grncontinue":"0.360395277951|0.360395626487|10429617|0","continue":"grncontinue||"},"query":{"pages":{"38690716":{"pageid":38690716,"ns":0,"title":"Alaine Chartrand","thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Alaine_Chartrand.jpg","width":267,"height":400},"pageimage":"Alaine_Chartrand.jpg"}}}}
```

this is the code, can anybody figure out why does it go to JSONException?

```
    String API = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500&utf8";

    //open connection with wikipedia.
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(API).openConnection();

    //read all the input from wikipedia.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream()));
    String responseSB = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
    in.close();
    JSONObject incomingJSON = new JSONObject(responseSB);

    //crashes here
    String mTitle = incomingJSON.getString("title");
    String mUrl = incomingJSON.getString("source");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice the JSON it is randomly generated but with specific format

**Case 1**

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"continue": {
    "grncontinue": "0.720220803439|0.720221273467|12887566|0",
    "continue": "grncontinue||"
},
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "4897672": {
            "pageid": 4897672,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "New Hope, Sunnyvale, Texas"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

`query` and `pages` were always existed, and in pages the key is always randomly generate, so it is `Map<String, JSONObject>` map of `String` key and `JSONObject` as value, Then you need to get the `title` value from map values

```
String API = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500&utf8";

    //open connection with wikipedia.
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(API).openConnection();

    //read all the input from wikipedia.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream()));
    String responseSB = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
    in.close();
    JSONObject incomingJSON = new JSONObject(responseSB);

  Map<String,JSONObject> map =  (Map<String, JSONObject>) incomingJSON.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages");

  map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(" The key is : "+k+" the title is : "+v.getString("title")));
```

**Case 2** With source

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"continue": {
    "grncontinue": "0.165621850014|0.165622038679|37982311|0",
    "continue": "grncontinue||"
},
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "57529788": {
            "pageid": 57529788,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Model Store",
            "thumbnail": {
                "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Australia_New_South_Wales_relief_location_map.png/500px-Australia_New_South_Wales_relief_location_map.png",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 443
            },
            "pageimage": "Australia_New_South_Wales_relief_location_map.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So `source` may not present in every response, handle with try catch

```
String API = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500&utf8";

    //open connection with wikipedia.
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(API).openConnection();

    //read all the input from wikipedia.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream()));
    String responseSB = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
    in.close();
    JSONObject incomingJSON = new JSONObject(responseSB);

  Map<String,JSONObject> map =  (Map<String, JSONObject>) incomingJSON.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages");

  map.forEach((k,v)->{
      System.out.println(" The key is : "+k+" the title is : "+v.getString("title"));  

      //use try catch to get source because you will not get the same response every time

      String source = v.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("source");
  });


}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting error "lambda expressions not supported at language level 7"
as I understand its gives this error because of map.forEach line. I'm not sure what is lambda expression. is there any other way doing it?

Comment: You are using jdk 7, lambda expressions are from jdk-8 so just use for loop to iterate map

Comment: No, I've come up with another solution which I've posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get title and source directly from JSON response because it has to contain multiple inner objects. Below is the code snap for reading title and source.

```
// new code
JSONObject incomingJSON = new JSONObject(responseSB);
JSONObject innerObject = incomingJSON.getJsonObject("query").getJsonObject("pages").getJsonObject("38690716");
String mTitle= innerObject.getString("title");
String mUrl= innerObject.getJsonObject("thumbnail").getString("source");


//crashes here
String mTitle = incomingJSON.getString("title");
String mUrl = incomingJSON.getString("source");
```

Comment: But it's not always 38690716

Comment: Ok, Try to use index instead of an object name.

Answer (score 0):

#### try this...

```
JSONObject incomingJSON = new JSONObject(responseSB);

JSONObject TitleObjects = incomingJSON.getJSONObject("query");
JSONObject j_Objects_01 = TitleObjects.getJSONObject("pages");
JSONObject j_Objects_02 = j_Objects_01.getJSONObject("38690716");

String mTitle = j_Objects_02.getString("title");
JSONObject j_Objects_03 = j_Objects_02.getJSONObject("thumbnail");
String mUrl = j_Objects_03.getString("source");
```

Comment: It's not always 38690716

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that the page id will change and the thumbnail is optional.

```
      // new code
      JSONObject incomingJSON = new JSONObject(responseSB);
      JSONObject pages = incomingJSON.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages");
      Iterator<String> it = pages.keys();

      while(it.hasNext()) {
          JSONObject page = pages.getJSONObject(it.next());
          String mTitle= page.getString("title");
          if(page.keySet().contains("thumbnail")) {
              String mUrl= page.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("source");
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

So because the ID kept changing, I've decided to go from another approach.
I've used the following code:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"source\":\"(.*?)\",\"width");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(responseSB);

        if (m.find()) {
            url = m.group(1);
        }

        p = Pattern.compile("\"title\":(.*?)\",\"thumbnail");
        m = p.matcher(responseSB);

        if (m.find()) {
            description = m.group(1);
        }
```